# Display Message and refresh page on a single click In Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to Refresh the page after displaying a message or alert saying "Successful" or vice-versa. How can I implement it?

I tried refresing code but it do not display message after that.

```
HTML CODE:

<div class="row" ng-controller="PublishManifestCtrl">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header bordered-bottom bordered-themeprimary">
            <i class="widget-icon fa fa-tasks themeprimary"></i>
            <span class="widget-caption themeprimary">Manifest Status</span>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-body">
            <form class="form-bordered" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last published to agents on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastPublishedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="padding-left: 8px;">Manifest was last updated by <b> {{manifeststatus.lastUpdatedByUser}} </b> on <b>{{manifeststatus.manifestLastedUpdatedDate}}</b>.</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                        <button id="PublishButton" class="btn btn-default shiny " ng-disabled="manifeststatus.enablePublishButton" ng-click="Save(manifeststatus)">Publish</button>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div id="statusDivPublish" ng-show="showstatus">
                        <alert type="{{alert.type}}">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

JS Code:

```
app.controller('PublishManifestCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

$scope.showstatus = false;

$http({
    url: $rootScope.WebApiURL + '/getmanifeststatus',
    method:get(),
    params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() }
}).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var options = { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric", hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" };

    data.manifestLastedUpdatedDate = (new Date(data.lastUpdatedDateTime)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    data.manifestLastPublishedDate = (new Date(data.lastPublishDateTime)).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
    var date1 = new Date(data.lastUpdatedDateTime);
    var date2 = new Date(data.lastPublishDateTime);
    data.enablePublishButton = date2.getTime() > date1.getTime();

    $scope.manifeststatus = data;
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error' + status);
    // log error
}); 
$scope.Save = function (data) {
    debugger;
    $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
    //refresh
     $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
     reload: true,
    inherit: false,
   notify: true
    });
    $scope.showstatus = true;
    $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
    $(".statusDivPublish").show();
)});
```

Implementation

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {
      // debugger;
        $http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');
       //made change
        $scope.manifeststatus = data;
        $scope.showstatus = true;
        $scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
        $(".statusDivPublish").show();


        //refresh
        $state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
            reload: true,
            inherit: false,
            notify: true
        });

    }   
  });
```

[image]

Originally It should be in this way:
[image]

Comment: But why you want to reload the page .angular works on two way databinding , if u want to change anything after service response then just make change the $scope

Comment: @maddygoround because, On that button click I am uploading current system date/time to DB and want to fetch it back on the screen.

Comment: Assing that date time to any scope var ..when ever you assign an value it will automatically reflect to html

Comment: @maddygoround I have made changes to post. About to add Html code too

Comment: @maddygoround  You mean to say I should add   $scope.manifeststatus = data; again in the save() function?

Comment: yes .this is why its called two way data binding.

Comment: @maddygoround  Ok, let me try it once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87953/discussion-between-sonam-g-and-maddygoround).

Answer (score 2):

in your html

```
<div>{{date}}</div>
```

in our angularjs file

```
$scope.Save = function (data) {

$http.post($rootScope.WebApiURL + '/updatemanifeststatus');

$scope.date = data.date;

//refresh
$scope.showstatus = true;
$scope.alert = { type: 'success', msg: 'Published Successfully.' };
$(".statusDivPublish").show();
$(".statusDivPublish").remove();

)});
```